# Find total data transferred for a video in AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am using CloudFront to distribute HLS video streams. The original video files that CloudFront uses are broken down into thousands of .ts files that are stored in S3 buckets. CloudFront Reports only seem to show total bytes transferred for the top 50 .ts files. Is it possible to find the total bytes transferred from CloudFront for an entire video? I am not interested in the amount of data transferred for only a selection of .ts files. Id like to see the total bytes transferred for the total video folder from which those .ts files are stored.

Comment: You might need to activate [CloudFront Access Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) and use Amazon Athena to [Query Amazon CloudFront Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can find statistics under CloudFront-> Usage Reports

[CloudFront Usage Reports - Data Transferred by Destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/usage-charts.html#usage-charts-data-transferred-by-destination)

Comment: It seems like I can only select a bucket in the 'Web Distribution' dropdown in the Usage Report.  However, in my setup, there are multiple videos in each bucket. Each video is represented by a folder, and each folder contains thousands of .ts objects (the videos are up to 3 hours long and contain 5 different HD and SD renditions). Im beginning to suspect that I can't drill down to determine the data transferred per video folder within each bucket within this AWS usage report.

Comment: The 'CloudFront Popular Objects Report' kind of does it, but only for the top 50 objects, and as I noted, there are thousands of .ts objects so this doesn't do much good.  I am looking into John's suggestion of using CloudFront Access Logs and Amazon Athena to Query Amazon CloudFront Logs. If I can export all the data transferred per object over a 24 hour period, I can figure it out.  But with multiple videos, and thousands of .ts objects per video, this will be a big report.